# how to collapse bootstrap navbar from the side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to collapse bootstrap navbar from the side?

If you view this [Bootstrap template self starter](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/) on a phone or by reducing your browser windows `width` then the `navbar` only shows project name. You can then view the whole menu by clicking on the small button on the side.

How can I change this to something similar to what stripe.com has for mobile browsers?

there navbar is from the side

Answer (score 4):

**Bootstrap 3**

Take a look at this "Off-canvas" [sidebar example on Bootply](http://bootply.com/92159). You'll see that the `nav-collapse` fills in from the right-side on smaller viewports.

---

**Bootstrap 4**:

[Create a responsive navbar sidebar "drawer" in Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996084/create-a-responsive-navbar-sidebar-drawer-in-bootstrap-4/48996139#48996139)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Befor you have `bootstrap-combined.min.css` file and `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in `head` section

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
       <li><a href="https://stripe.com/docs">Documentation</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://support.stripe.com/">Help &amp; Support</a></li>

        <li class="button"><a href="https://manage.stripe.com/login">Sign in</a></li>


    </ul>

    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->

 Fiddle
```

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjw4C/1/)