# Looking for a Bootstrap-4 code for sidebar navigation

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Am looking for a bootstrap code that will create a sidebar navigation with dropdown menu on an admin dashboard am building.

Please am waiting for an answer

This is my code:

Home

aaa

bb

Forms

aaa

bb

UI Elements

aaa

bb

Tables

aaa

bb

Data presention

aaa

bb

Comment: It's expected you at least attempt to do the code yourself. This is not a free code writing service.

Comment: See this Q/A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996084/create-a-responsive-navbar-sidebar-drawer-in-bootstrap-4/48996139#48996139

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar

Has the following sub-tuts:

1. Basic sidebar: Static collapsible Bootstrap sidebar menu
2. Basic sidebar: Fixed & collapsible Bootstrap sidebar navigation
3. Advanced sidebar: Fixed scrollable & collapsible Bootstrap sidebar with page transparent overlay
4. Advanced sidebar: Partially collapsing static sidebar (i.e. the sidebar will not collapse fully but to a compressed state)
5. Bonus section: Further Improvements - Fancy animated button and 3D animated sidebar

Comment: Heyyer, if this answered your question would you mind upvoting it to offset the downvote? Many thx and good luck with Bootstrap. BTW, did you know there are [a few great templates](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_templates.asp) for slapping together quick sites at w3schools? I've used the [Company](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp) theme several times for my own use. (I don't often recommend w3schools, but sometimes they create helpful stuff. I also refer to their [css colors chart](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp) quite often.). : )