# Navbar button collapse to sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sidebar

Is there a way to implement a side bar on the collapse button on the navbar?

When I reduce the screen, I get the collapse button on the navbar with all the buttons on it.

When I click on that collapse button it expands the navbar and shows the buttons. Is there a way that instead of this expand button, it shows a side bar on the right or wrong side occupying the entire screen and showing the nav buttons?

[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/wYCyt7CCZD)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question and what you're trying to accomplish? What does "right or wrong side" mean? Do you mean like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49535297/171456  or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59007911/171456?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below css in your file

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
#collapsibleNavbar {position: fixed;top: 0;left: -100%;bottom: 0;display: block;max-width: 320px;width: calc(100% - 80px);min-height: 100%;z-index: 999;transition: all 0.3s ease;background: #000000;}
#collapsibleNavbar.show {left: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Perfct, 
that was what I wanted!