# Bootstrap collapse sidebar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I try to do a sidebar that we can collapse (hide) or display, the goal is that the sidebar kind of push the content on the right.

I've done that, but when I display the sidebar the content is compressed/not pushed, we keep the responsivity.
If I add `flex-shrink-0` to the main part, it works well for the sidebar push content behavior, but I totally loose responsivity.

I would like somthink like https://fontawesome.com/ when the view is minimised, I don't know how explain it.

```css
#sidebar.collapsing.width {
    height: auto;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width .35s ease;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>The page title</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch vh-100">
    <nav>
        <div id="sidebar" class="h-100 collapse width show">
            <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column p-2 text-white bg-dark" style="width: 280px;">
                <a class="m-2" href="#">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/110x50?text=Logo" alt="Aviron Tours Métropole">
                </a>

                <hr>

                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Link 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <hr class="mt-auto">

                <ul class="nav flex-column small">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link link-secondary" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link link-secondary" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <hr>

                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle"
                       id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://robohash.org/JD.png?set=set4"
                             alt="mdo" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle me-2">
                        <strong>John Doe</strong>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My profile</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto bg-light">
        <nav class="d-flex bg-white shadow-sm" style="--bs-breadcrumb-divider: '>';" aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <button id="toggle-sidebar" class="btn ms-2 me-3 py-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="sidebar">
                <span class="bi bi-list"></span>
            </button>

            <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0 pt-3">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="bi bi-house-door-fill"></span> Home
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </nav>

        <main class="my-3 px-3">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vitae tellus suscipit, ultrices mauris a,
                cursus nunc. Morbi odio enim, congue a dignissim et, rutrum ac nunc. Donec maximus ipsum nec diam
                facilisis, quis aliquam justo pretium. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
                posuere cubilia curae; Sed porta sollicitudin nisi, tempus luctus dui semper scelerisque. Vivamus quis
                turpis arcu. Aenean efficitur tortor vel neque ultricies mattis. Quisque eu pretium metus, sed pulvinar
                nisl. Proin scelerisque ex non lacus ornare egestas. Pellentesque vel rhoncus tellus. Nullam laoreet
                sapien nec enim blandit, nec pretium dolor tempus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sit amet felis vulputate,
                auctor neque at, tempus ipsum. Quisque tempus bibendum ultricies. Praesent non lectus tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Integer hendrerit lectus non quam efficitur dapibus. Vestibulum blandit nisi at neque tincidunt aliquet.
                Aenean rutrum risus sed eros imperdiet, sit amet venenatis justo faucibus. Proin at vestibulum sapien.
                Nunc mollis odio ultricies, vulputate lacus quis, auctor elit. Curabitur vitae sem sed ipsum pretium
                ullamcorper. Nunc rutrum, purus blandit ullamcorper luctus, mauris neque ultricies orci, a aliquam risus
                tellus et erat. Suspendisse id risus sodales, varius enim at, rutrum purus.
            </p>
            <p>
                Donec porta urna porta nisl eleifend ultricies. Aenean iaculis congue neque vitae posuere. Donec vitae
                pellentesque leo, sed convallis eros. Fusce auctor scelerisque justo, sit amet lobortis augue tempus sit
                amet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis id est tortor. Suspendisse arcu turpis, lobortis non auctor vitae,
                accumsan sit amet risus. Suspendisse finibus mi bibendum libero elementum, vel malesuada elit sagittis.
            </p>
            <p>
                Aenean in ipsum neque. Quisque ligula erat, maximus sed porta a, mattis et massa. Morbi a sapien
                molestie, interdum sapien sed, tristique lectus. Integer hendrerit, lacus quis volutpat sodales, eros
                nisi bibendum urna, non pharetra enim velit eu lectus. Nam dignissim nibh nec nunc finibus eleifend.
                Praesent consequat molestie odio et auctor. Sed faucibus urna vel pretium viverra. Proin non mi eu
                mauris mollis mattis eu quis ante. Sed auctor porttitor tellus, non porta diam posuere et. Integer
                aliquam mi nulla, ac porttitor lacus efficitur vitae. Fusce tortor arcu, mollis eu lectus at, fringilla
                mollis nisl. Integer quis aliquam risus. Phasellus vitae rhoncus dolor. Aenean eu urna a velit convallis
                auctor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Nam nunc ante, feugiat nec commodo ac, blandit nec sapien. Maecenas eget tempor nunc. Vivamus eu
                malesuada ante. Sed porta elementum nunc ut vestibulum. Quisque facilisis eros aliquam, tristique quam
                eu, scelerisque metus. Nulla ultricies elit at diam posuere, eu lobortis mauris pellentesque.
                Pellentesque pulvinar tortor sit amet neque suscipit consectetur.
            </p>
            <p>
                Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Etiam commodo
                diam purus, nec dapibus neque aliquet eget. Aliquam in lobortis urna, nec bibendum sem. Praesent eget
                ultricies neque. Morbi pharetra in velit id tristique. Mauris tristique sodales lacus accumsan gravida.
                Integer sed lorem nec urna egestas mollis vitae id turpis. Sed non dolor odio. Etiam congue nunc pretium
                nibh bibendum, vitae maximus dui dapibus. Donec euismod venenatis nisl, vel laoreet eros efficitur
                molestie. Fusce pharetra, enim nec eleifend imperdiet, tellus quam bibendum tellus, vel blandit orci
                sapien ut erat.
            </p>
            <p>
                Nam bibendum nisi id scelerisque feugiat. Vestibulum cursus arcu sed elit blandit, ac hendrerit magna
                iaculis. Mauris suscipit mauris a porttitor tempor. Vestibulum quis euismod risus, dictum blandit dui.
                Praesent et sapien in dui blandit aliquam. Integer quis auctor augue. Ut efficitur aliquam condimentum.
                Aenean dolor nibh, gravida non elit eget, euismod laoreet ipsum. Vestibulum iaculis diam sed felis
                cursus pulvinar. Proin a purus varius, pulvinar quam nec, fringilla nisl. Morbi in nulla nisl. Sed in
                ipsum quis lorem volutpat feugiat. Proin finibus consequat nisi varius ultrices. Donec ultricies finibus
                tellus, aliquet viverra sapien tincidunt nec. Suspendisse mollis imperdiet vehicula. Sed commodo purus
                vel mauris vulputate accumsan.
            </p>
            <p>
                Proin ac massa quis orci dapibus interdum. Aenean semper ipsum ac urna pharetra ultrices. Nunc id
                vehicula urna. Integer sollicitudin, enim sit amet fermentum dapibus, elit nisl convallis augue, eget
                imperdiet velit ex vel nisl. Pellentesque feugiat libero sed felis pulvinar tempus. Suspendisse non
                lacus ex. Quisque facilisis dolor augue, ac mollis est consequat non. Mauris sed libero vestibulum,
                dignissim metus ut, bibendum leo. Praesent viverra sem eget imperdiet consequat. Vestibulum dapibus erat
                eu elit ornare porta. Nunc tristique leo eget turpis luctus, sit amet lacinia odio elementum. Donec eget
                dignissim quam, eleifend pharetra lorem. Sed aliquet molestie arcu mollis bibendum. Nullam efficitur
                odio ut nibh euismod fermentum.
            </p>
            <p>
                Vivamus laoreet ultrices orci, a cursus purus porttitor eget. Donec ut blandit turpis. Maecenas arcu
                tellus, pretium et nibh sed, pulvinar tempor arcu. Cras tempor a risus a molestie. Vestibulum ante ipsum
                primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Etiam vitae massa neque. Integer vel
                pretium tellus. Praesent in metus eget mauris porttitor faucibus. Donec aliquam, mi viverra rutrum
                tempus, neque lorem luctus urna, a suscipit metus leo vitae quam. Integer vestibulum vulputate purus a
                euismod.
            </p>
            <p>
                Etiam vel magna felis. Donec sollicitudin condimentum ipsum, eu auctor dolor fermentum id. Pellentesque
                tristique vitae lorem quis accumsan. Sed laoreet arcu sit amet varius fringilla. Class aptent taciti
                sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed pellentesque rhoncus dolor,
                vel molestie augue sollicitudin ut. Vestibulum in felis vitae nibh condimentum euismod. Suspendisse id
                purus sapien. Vivamus sapien diam, iaculis vel massa sed, ultricies dignissim ligula. Fusce interdum non
                massa ut lacinia. Mauris facilisis sodales faucibus. Sed hendrerit facilisis mi lobortis aliquam. Proin
                ullamcorper erat pulvinar neque imperdiet, et tempor odio finibus. Vestibulum tortor nisl, venenatis
                placerat odio at, commodo tincidunt diam.
            </p>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like it works. And it is responsible. Could you tell me what it is not working?

Comment: It’s clear (clear enough) – the idea is the content shifts towards the right (going off-screen, in a way) when the sidebar animates in from the left. One option would be to use the new Bootstrap [offcanvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/) function. It won’t animate the main content, but it will bring in the sidebar from the left (or right or top) and it includes a shading over the main content so if the user taps or clicks anywhere on the displayed main content, the sidebar will close.

Comment: Got it. IMO the offcanvas isn't the best option because it's designed to overlay (position: fixed), not push (position: relative) the sidebar so it could work but would need some extra CSS.

Comment: @RichDeBourke thanks for your answer, the OffCanvas is interesting but don't really match my needs. In my case I want to keep it open on large screen for example to navigate, and switch open/close on small screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this. Just use `w-100` on the main content so that it's forced to 100% width.

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch vh-100 overflow-hidden ">
    <nav>
        <div id="sidebar" class="h-100 collapse width show">
            <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column p-2 text-white bg-dark" style="width: 280px;">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 overflow-auto bg-light w-100">
        <nav class="d-flex bg-white shadow-sm" style="--bs-breadcrumb-divider: '>';" aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <button id="toggle-sidebar" class="btn ms-2 me-3 py-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="sidebar">
                <span class="bi bi-list"></span>
            </button>
            <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0 pt-3">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="bi bi-house-door-fill"></span> Home </a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
        <main class="my-3 px-3">
            <p> .... </p>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/QIUxMUYbLB)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your wanswer, it works pretty well, do you know ho keep the scrollbar on the right when we open the sidebar ? Actually, the sidebar go out of the screen I think.

Comment: I'll look at the way they do that on the FontAwesome site, as they use bootstrap and exactly have the behavior I want. When the sidebar is open I want a normal behavior, and only push outside the screen when I open the menu after.

Comment: It would require more tweaks to make it exactly like FA. That is a fixed position menu so that is doesn't scroll away when scrolling down the page. Sidebars can get [very complex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48996139/171456)